# How to duplicate a HttpWebRequest when GetResponse returns 407

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-407

I've writing an extension method for HttpWebRequest which will check some propertys and has a general failure resulution.

One of the failures I want to handle is 407 Proxy Authentication Required.
When this happens I show the user a login mask and use the returned user/password for the credentials and start a new request.

The Problem I currently facing is that I can't use the Original request (now with proxy credentials) to reissue the request. I also don't get the data from the old request to fill in a new one :/

How do you elegantyl handle 407 in c#?

---

The Code I currently want to use looks like this:

```
public static class WebRequestExtension
{
    public static HttpWebResponse GetResponseWithProxyCheck(this HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        return GetResponseWithProxyCheck(request, 0);
    }
    private static HttpWebResponse GetResponseWithProxyCheck(this HttpWebRequest request, int numberOfCalls)
    {
        try
        {
            if (request.Proxy != null && credential != null)
                request.Proxy.Credentials = credential;
            return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException w)
        {
            var webResponse = w.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ProxyAuthenticationRequired && numberOfCalls < 3)
            {
                ProxyDialog pd = new ProxyDialog();
                var ret = pd.ShowDialog();
                if (ret == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    credential = new NetworkCredential(pd.User, pd.Password);
                    var newRequest = (HttpWebRequest);// somehow duplicate the old Request
                    return newRequest.GetResponseWithProxyCheck(numberOfCalls + 1);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static ICredentials credential;
}
```

Comment: I am confused by your question. You issued the original request, right? So you should know the properties of that request? Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: What I searched for was a way to easaly duplicate the request. Like a try around the send and in the catch setting the proxy credentials and use send again. I didn't want to handle the enter credentials and send request again every time I call Create WebRequest. I tried to resolve this implementing my own Stream that send the data to the base stream and also store the sended data. I'm currently testing this.